# Parse Server, purpose and benefits

Tags: parse-server

I am trying to wrap my head around Parse server and have the following questions.

1. Is this a hosted service on AWS? and what is the benefit of using this?
2. What is the relationship between Parse server and MongoDB?
3. On the parse server site the following is stated, **The Parse hosted backend will be fully retired on January 28, 2017**  does this mean this is obsolete and I should avoid using this?
4. How do I implement security (authentication and authorization) on this?

Answer (score 8):

I'll try to be brief:

1. The open source Parse-Server is solution that you host yourself as if it was any other web application. You can host your own instance of Parse-Server on platforms like AWS, Heroku, etc. There are lots of benefits including being able to use many more adapters (other push notification services, file storage services, etc) as well as performance improvements (no artificial limits on req/sec). Several new features are being added to the open source version that are not supported in the Facebook hosted solution.
2. By default Parse-Server uses MongoDB as database store (default), just like a Rails Application would use PostgreSQL as a database store. Latest Parse-Server can also use PostgreSQL as a database store.
3. Parse-Server is not obsolete and far from it. The shutdown date refers to the hosted solution that Facebook provided.
4. Parse-Server provides these features out of the box, one of the many reasons it is very popular. For this I recommend reading the documentation: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/.

**Disclaimer**:
I work on the [Parse Server Ruby Client SDK](https://github.com/modernistik/parse-stack) that is compatible with the open source server.